# Repository pattern in C# without Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, class, model-view-controller, repository

I have a new project that requires me to connect to Oracle 9i. I want to use the repository pattern (which I am new at) to organise my code. I will use some stored procedures for some queries.

I want to write my code in such a way that there should be no duplication and also following the best practices.

Please check my code below and let me know if I am doing it right. I have a feeling that I am not.

I tried to read other posts on the same topic but no luck.

```
public interface IDeliveryRepository : IDisposable
{
    IEnumerable<Delivery> GetDeliveries();
    Task GetDelivery(int id);
    void Insert(Delivery delivery);
    void Delete(Delivery delivery);
    void Update(Delivery delivery);
}
```

Repository:

```
public class DeliveryRepository: IDeliveryRepository
{
        public Delivery GetDelivery(int id)
        {
            Delivery delivery = null;
            var sql = "SELECT d.id , o.owner_id, o.name FROM delivery d JOIN owner o on o.id = d.owner_id where id = :t";

            using (var con = new OracleConnection(AppConfig.CALL_CENTER_CONNECTION_STRING))
            {
                con.Open();

                using (var cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, con))
                {
                    cmd.BindByName = true;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("t", id);

                    using (var oraReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (oraReader.Read())
                        {
                            delivery = new Delivery
                            {
                                Id = oraReader.GetString(oraReader.GetOrdinal("id")),
                                Owner = new Owner
                                {
                                    Id = oraReader.GetString(oraReader.GetOrdinal("owner_id")),
                                    Name = oraReader.GetString(oraReader.GetOrdinal("name"))
                                }
                            };
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return delivery;
        }
```

.
.
.
.
.

Comment: Just use dapper and save your a lot of time

Comment: @MichaelRandall thank you a 1000s times, that is exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make your repository IDisposable, and to use Task you should implement your entire class with the [Async programming model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/). I have updated your code below which should get you close to a compiling baseline that you can then extend.

```
 // Removed the IDisposable interface
 public interface IDeliveryRepository
 {
     IEnumerable<Delivery> GetDeliveries();

     // Changed the below from a Task to a Delivery as the return type. To use Task, 
     // your entire implementation should be asynchronous.
     Delivery GetDelivery(int id);
     void Insert(Delivery delivery);
     void Delete(Delivery delivery);
     void Update(Delivery delivery);
 }

 public class DeliveryRepository: IDeliveryRepository
 {
     public Delivery GetDelivery(int id)
     {
         Delivery delivery = null;
         var sql = "SELECT d.id , o.owner_id, o.name FROM delivery d JOIN owner o on o.id = d.owner_id where id = :t";
         using (var con = new OracleConnection(AppConfig.CALL_CENTER_CONNECTION_STRING))
         {
             con.Open();
             using (var cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, con))
             {
                 cmd.BindByName = true;
                 cmd.Parameters.Add("t", id);
                 using (var oraReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                 {
                     while (oraReader.Read())
                     {
                         delivery = new Delivery
                         {
                             Id = oraReader.GetString(oraReader.GetOrdinal("id")),
                             Owner = new Owner
                                {
                                 Id = oraReader.GetString(oraReader.GetOrdinal("owner_id")),
                                 Name = oraReader.GetString(oraReader.GetOrdinal("name"))
                             }
                         };
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         return delivery;
     }

   public void Insert(Delivery delivery)
   {
       /// Add your code here 
       throw new NotImplementedException();
   }


   public void Delete(Delivery delivery);
   {
       /// Add your code here 
       throw new NotImplementedException();
   }

   public void Update(Delivery delivery);
   {
       /// Add your code here 
       throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Delivery> GetDeliveries();
    {
       /// Add your code here 
       throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I really appreciate it. The tool that I was looking for was Dapper.